# Sharing an image from .NET MAUI app on iOS

Tags: maui

I'd like to share an image from my MAUI app. I am using following code:

```
        await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
        {
            Title = "Share Image",
            File = new ShareFile("fsfs.jpg")
        });
```

Sharing works fine however, the share window does not display a thumbnail. Also when I share an image from elsewhere, image name is displayed without extension, and with thumbnail.

MAUI documentation mentions that the filetype is passed onto share window via mime-type and no further action would be needed.

I tried MauiImage instead of MauiAsset, hoping that this might signalled that this was an image but it didn't help. The same issue with PNG files, so it is not a JPG related problem either.

What can I do to make sure the image is recognised in the share window and a thumbnail is displayed?

[image]

Comment: I assume this is just a limitation of the MAUI implementation of the share service.  You can see the iOS code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/a6c99972618fe6d042e8f066ec479cd1b41b2a67/src/Essentials/src/Share/Share.ios.cs#L12)

Comment: Thank you Jason, trying to compare MAUI's code to Swift examples, with my limited knowledge. Seems like MAUI is passing an NSObject, while swift examples seems to be sending a UIImage, otherwise the logic is very similar.

Comment: You could raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) for this.

Comment: Done, it has gone into "to be looked at one day" pile... I am trying to create my own share service, but lots to learn there. Will share here if I get any progress.

Comment: Thanks for your work. I've seen it here, [Problems when sharing an image](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20434). Thanks.